# Research on (or less formal information about) self-directed time

Tags: software-development

[Atlassian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian) has a concept they refer to as [ShipIt Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Motivation), which are

> where software developers can spend 24 hours tackling any problem they like.

I've also heard this referred to as *Innovation days* in a different case.

I've been encouraged to work on a plan for something similar at my current workplace, and as much as I would like this to happen, I'm not sure where to start.

So I'm wondering, has there been any research done in this area, which I've called 'self-directed time' in the title, about what benefits and pitfalls there are? And if no "real" research is available, are there other, less formal, sources of information available?

Comment: Related question: [How can a company implement a “20% time” program like Google's?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/468/how-can-a-company-implement-a-20-time-program-like-googles)

Comment: self directed time is sort of implied by salaried status maybe you ought to take that out its not adding anything here.

Answer (score 2):

I want to share some experiences I made and collected from others about self-directed or "20% time".

## TL;DR:

There are **different ways of doing this** and reading about experiences, it can sound like it promotes everything from cleaner tables to eternal youth, but **try it**. **Don't hike up your expectations** but **let it work itself out** and see what you can reap from it. It's **different for every team** but I have yet to see a company that really tried to embrace it take a loss in the process, when examined objectively.

---

## Examples:

#### Work on your own projects

I've worked in an environment where we tested this idea and it worked quite well for a while. We **dedicated every friday to this** and **interesting projects** came out of it ranging **from little libraries to full-blown test frameworks**. In some way or another **all of those projects even helped the company** we worked for at the time, even though there was no mandate that it had to be for the company.

#### Select projects from a list provided by the company

In another team, this was fun too. **We were able to influence the list some** and had a good time **working on the projects alone as well as in teams**.

#### Work on whatever piece of existing software you think needs work

This is what the company of a friend of mine do. They have **'hackathon days'** where **team members get to work on their product, improving whatever they want**. It only **has to be finished by the end of the hackathon** - for the presentation.

---

## Features:

#### Motivation

Working on your own projects, bits that you **really want fixed/refactored** from your daily work or similar things **at your own pace and direction** is very **rewarding** to a lot of programmers.

#### Getting out of the box

It **sparks creativity, thinking through a whole stack, planning and coordinating** with other team members and possibly presentation skills.

#### Extending/Spreading knowledge

Often **people worked together** on projects to **learn from or with each other** new skills, technologies or libraries.

#### Improvements to company products or assets

Almost **everything** I've ever seen done in this kind of environment **eventually proved useful to the company**.

---

## Benefits:

#### To the team

Teams tend to **work together better** and be **more resilient** to unexpected sick days or similar loss of resources. Team members usually **feel happier, more fulfilled by their work and better in general**. Even what could be called rivalries or outright wars within teams sometimes can be reduced or turned around by this.

#### To the company

Management can **plan better, because bottlenecks (at least skill- or knowlege-wise) reduce**. **Quality of work** delivered often improves, from continuous peer-review by teaming up and from thinking outside the box which leads to **new and unexpected connections** and (warning: *buzz-word*) synergies. Not to mention the benefits from **improved culture and greater perceived happiness** with the job, which also **carries over into other teams** and completely unrelated departments.

---

## Source:

- Personal experience (contact me, I'm happy to talk your ears off about this)
- Anecdotal evidence (also happy to relay to others so you can learn from their experience)